# Is the entry point for the same for a C++ app as it is for a C app?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, entry-point

I know that when I compile a C source file with a `main()` function in Visual C++, the entry point for my program will be `mainCRTStartup()`.

But what if I compiled my source file as a C++ file, will the entry point also be `mainCRTStartup()`, or does C++ have a different entry point?

Comment: That depends on which CRT (C RunTime Library) you use.

Comment: @aschepler But when I compile the source file as a C++ file, I am no longer using a C Run-time Library, but rather I am now using a C++ Run-time Library, or am I missing something?

Comment: The entry point is defined by the particular RTL library you link against.  It has nothing to do with the language you code in. But, to answer your question, the default C++ RTL library in VC++ also uses a `mainCRTStartup()` entry point.

Comment: The entry point for your C++ (or C) program on a hosted environment is `main` That's defined by the standards. Anything else is implementation-defined. Why do you care about what heppens before the program is setup as required by the language? E.g. static variables initialised, constructors for such called, etc. And don't spam tags. C is not C++. And no, you cannot compile C code with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Microsoft's run-time library is the same for C as it is for C++, and it's still called the CRT. Yes, it's still `mainCRTStartup`. Why do you need to know this? This is an implementation detail, not something the programmer should ever have to worry about.

Comment: @aschepler the question specifically says it's compiling with Visual C++, how many runtime libraries are available for it? And I don't understand the downvotes and close votes, this seems like the kind of specific question that should be welcome here.

Comment: @Olaf actually with Visual C++ it's as easy as changing your filename to '*.c'. Or at least it used to be, I hope it hasn't changed over the years. But the compiler isn't terribly C-standard compliant in that mode.

Comment: @MarkRansom - the C and C++ communities on SO seem to get somewhat upset when people ask about implementation details of compiler toolchains.  I think it's because they don't want to encourage poor practices that often arise when depending on those details.  These kinds of questions seem to get get less negative reaction when they include information about *why* the implementation details are being researched.

Comment: @MichaelBurr C and C++ already give you so many ways of shooting yourself in the foot, I wouldn't worry about providing another bullet. On the other hand a healthy curiosity is a good thing, understanding the mechanics of how things work can be very beneficial even if you don't directly apply it. If a stern warning is required then a good answer would supply it.

Comment: @MarkRansom: C and C++ are different languages. The times C++ was a superset of C are gone since decades. Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics. Renaming the file and compiling one as the other is a good way to unexpected/wrong results. Whoever told you different should leavel the 20ies century and learn the languages. And this one is not about any of the languages, but a **specific implementation** of C++. Wrt the languages, see my comment above!

Comment: @MarkRansom: It is not the communities, but a fact the languages have split long time ago. With C++11 and C99 the differences massively grew.

Comment: @Olaf thus my comment on how compiling C sources in Visual C++ is not very standard conformant. While there may be good reasons for not doing so, as long as it's still physically possible then this is an on-topic question.

Comment: @MarkRansom: That's not even what OP is asking about. It is completely unrelated to the question!

Comment: @Olaf, I'm not sure there was *ever* a time C++ was a proper superset of C. I think `int new = 7;` would have *always* been valid in the latter, invalid in the former :-)

Comment: And, bods, keep in mind Microsoft have *explicitly* stated in the past that VS is a C++ compiler, *not* a C one except insofar as one is a "sort-of" subset of the other.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Agreed, let apart the new reserved keywords, it somehow was when C++ was a C precompiler. But as I wrote, these times are gone since some decades now (I was careful with 20 years, it was mor like 25-30 years). I generally discourage compiling C code with a MS compiler at all. It is not compliant since 18 years now and most likely never will be. They were very clear not supporting the full feature-set at least, including VLAs. As you wrote, they explicitly concentrate on C++. I'm fine with that, there are better FOSS compilers anyway with gcc and clang.

Comment: @Cody Gray *"Microsoft's run-time library is the same for C as it is for C++, and it's still called the CRT"* I could be wrong, but this page says that the C-Runtime library (**LIBCMT.LIB** for Multithreaded) and the Standard C++ library (**LIBCPMT.LIB** for Multithreaded) are two different things: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/154419/frequently-asked-questions-about-the-standard-c-library

Comment: There are more components in the C++ runtime library, needed to support C++ language features like constructors, destructors, RTTI, etc. The C runtime doesn't need that, so they aren't provided. The fundamentals are the same, though. In other words, the C++ runtime is built on top of the same base as the C runtime. This is mostly because Microsoft is not and has never really been a vendor for a C compiler; they focus on C++ support. The C runtime library just pulls out the C++ bits.

Comment: @Cody Gray If I understood you correctly, **LIBCPMT.LIB** is basically **LIBCMT.LIB** plus the C++ stuff. Now I have noticed two things: 1) **LIBCPMT.LIB** (8 KB) is half the size of **LIBCMT.LIB** (16 KB) 2) I inspected **LIBCPMT.LIB** and it doesn't contain the functions `mainCRTStartup()` and `printf()`.

Comment: LIBCPMT.LIB is the additional C++ bits. That explains why it's significantly smaller, and why it doesn't contain all the functions from the C runtime library. *Both* get linked in.

Comment: Interesting trivia: starting with VC++ 2015 (I think), Microsoft's **C** runtime is written mostly in C++!